# Fullscreen responsive background image in CSS

Tags: html, css, image, background-image

I want to make [this image](http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Angry-Birds-Star-Wars-Menu.png) as the background image of my webpage. However , the problem is that the image doesn't cover the whole of the page, as you may see in [this preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/LmHIak79oPtEaZCAUZbx?p=preview) , and it gets repeated at the rightmost end . Is there a way so that the image covers the whole page (be it any way , stretching , re-sizing , or something new).

**My Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Angry Birds Star Wars</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <style>
            body {
                background: url('http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Angry-Birds-Star-Wars-Menu.png');
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body></body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

### UPDATE:

I have now finally come to believe that there is almost nothing that can get that image to fit exactly to my PC screen. I am now ok , and am moving further , please don't post answers now.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/mufufa/1/)**

```
background: url(image.jpg) fixed 50%;
background-size: cover;                 /* PS: Use separately here cause of Safari bug */
```

<sup>The `fixed` (background-attachment) is optional.</sup>

---

The above is just a shorthand for:

```
background-image      : url(image.jpg);
background-attachment : fixed;
background-position   : 50% 50%;     /* or: center center */
background-size       : cover;       /* CSS3 */
```

---

You've could in all modern browsers **but Safari** use:

```
background: url(image.jpg) fixed 50% / cover;
```

where the `/` is used in background shorthand to separate and distinguish `position` from `size` (cause *position* accepts both single and multiple (X,Y) values), but Safari has a bug with this `/` shorthand so use as described above.

Comment: @GaurangTandon How is this answer different than my earlier answer?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan So basically your version lacks support for older browsers. Right.

Comment: @jCuber `?` older browsers do not have `background-cover` at all, so please explain your statement

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan My bad, I was using [outdated information.](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `background-size` attribute and set the background repeat to `no-repeat`.

Like this:

```
body { 
        background: url('http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Angry-Birds-Star-Wars-Menu.png') no-repeat center center fixed;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4RXwZ/)

Comment: Ok , that made it a little better , but the image is cut of a little from the bottom and top (compare the [original](http://www.androidtapp.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Angry-Birds-Star-Wars-Menu.png) and the result)

Comment: @GaurangTandon That's because of `center center` positioning. Just change it to `top left` if you want the background image to be anchored on the top left corner of the image.

Comment: That cut it of even more , `center center` was better

Answer (score 1):

Set this for your background image

```
background-size: cover
```

Comment: you can't use it like that, make them separate attributes like background-image and background-size

Answer (score 0):

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-position: top left;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

should do the trick. Notice - you can combine position & repeat into the initial background attribute

And apply

```
html, body { min-height: 100%; min-width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can always use a absolute position div to 100% width and height with z-index so that it can be a background, then you can insert the image with same css for it.
thanks

Comment: -5 Nonono if you tried what you said, the image will stretch as you resize your window. and that's **bad**. Hope you don't like distorted images... :) And about the `z-index` there's absolutely no need to set z-indexes in that case.