# Im trying to make a "jumbotron" img

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to make an image stretch 100% over the site, and when I shrink the window the picture should stay centered and shrink from the sides. Here is what I have tried:

HTML

```
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="img/large.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.full-width{
    width:100%;
    height:450px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.full-width img {
    width:75%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: you mean like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556896/fullscreen-responsive-background-image-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simply `cover` as your `background-size` property:

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/xiriti/1/edit)***

```
.full-width{
    width:100%;
    height:450px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    background:url(img/large.jpg) 50% / cover;
}
```

the `50%` will center it, and `cover` with fill your DIV element with your background image.

Comment: oh! Thank you man! That was bugging me for two days now, couldnt find an answer wich didnt shrink the image as i shrunk the window! 

Much appreciated

Comment: Im having some problem using this attribute. The background-image is not displayed in the safari browser..

Answer (score 0):

If you use your image as a background, you can use the `background-size` property in conjunction with sizing the div over the whole document.

```
.full-width {
 position:fixed;
 top:0;
 left:0;
 right:0;
 bottom:0;
 background:url(img/large.jpg) no-repeat center center;
 background-size:100% auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed `display: block` (`margin: 0 auto` only works on block elements) and `height: auto` on the image:

```css
.full-width{
    width:100%;
    height:450px;
    margin-bottom:50px;
}

.full-width img {
    width:75%;
    margin:0 auto;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-width">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maryisdead/60mej71c/)

Answer (score 0):

Change the width of **.full-width img** from 75% to 100%.