# Responsive Image Background

Tags: css, image, twitter-bootstrap, background

I have a picture as my background but I can't figure out how to make my code responsive such that the image stays consistent when I decrease the browser window.Here is my code:

```
body {
margin-top: 50px; 
}


.full {
background: url(../melissa.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullscreen responsive background image in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556896/fullscreen-responsive-background-image-in-css)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a responsive `background` look at this [SAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/greenfoxx/ehar71km/1/)

```
.full {
    height: 500px;
    background-image: url('image.jpg');
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will make it responsive for you.
Just add the **height and width to 100%**.

```
.full {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background: url(../melissa.jpg) no-repeat center center scroll;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm assuming .full is a div which contains the background you want right? if that's the case, the width and height set to 100% will only make the div that big, which may still not work as he's using 100% to the height and thus you would need to set 100% to the body or any other container that .full is in. You can just set the background-size: cover, background-position:center center, backgorund-repeat:norepeat, and just give .full it's height and width. That should make the backgound always filling the whole container.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your help. Unfortunately, on mobile now the background image and the text are cut off and do not fit the screen. Any tips?

Comment: Can you make an edit and update the code how it looks now? does the text have any style to it? a codepen would be perfect