# creating a background image that will be both responsive contained and cover the entire browser width and height

Tags: html, css, background, responsive

I find myself struggling to have a background with an image that will keep itself contained, responsive and also cover the entire body width and height at all resolution.  also, there are my own elements like ul and paragraphs that has to be located in a specific area of the background and scale properly with it, keeping itself in that same exact location compared to the background in different resolutions of the screen. I know that the strategy is different for different designs, but any sort of general strategy tip that relates to what i said, especially to the elements that has to be located in a specific place in the background at all desktop browser sizes, will help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18556896/fullscreen-responsive-background-image-in-css

Comment: have a google for `background-size` - you have all your options there.  As for keeping an item in a certain position of the background, you will probably need some sort of js library for that